# What test should I use if:

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm trying not to have a seizure among the bunch of numbers and data I have.  My experiment data consists of three non-equal, non-parametric groups, and I need to compare those groups to state if there exists statistical difference between those groups.  Which will be the best test I can use to achieve so?  Group 1 data: n=12, mean=0.886, SD=0.74 | Group 2 data: n=16, mean= 0.554, SD= 0.39 | Group 3 data: n=13, mean= 0.79, SD= 0.68

Any help, suggestions or comments will be very helpful and appreciated!

Comment: Do you have all your data, or just the summaries you listed here?

Comment: I have all of my data if you need it

Comment: I don't need the data; I was just making sure that you had it available and weren't solely relying on the summary statistics for your analysis.

Comment: Could you explain what a "non-parametric group" is and what you mean by a "statistical difference"?

Comment: Whuber: the data among my groups are non-parametric.  What I mean by statistical difference, is (the goal of my statistic work) to evaluate if there is a statistical significance among the group means.

Comment: Data are neither parametric nor nonparametric; those are adjectives that apply to models or techniques. If you mean "not normally distributed" that's not at all the same thing as "nonparametric" and similarly "parametric" is not at all the same thing as "normally distributed" -- one can fit parametric non-normal models and correspondingly, one can happily use nonparametric procedures on data drawn from normal distributions. Please amend your post to more clearly express the actual situation.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Glen_b, as you said and correcting my initial statement, my data is not normally distributed. And sorry if I'm not making myself clear. My statistic skills are far from robust.

Comment: The misuse of terminology is almost certainly not your fault. There's an unfortunate tendency for elementary statistics books (especially in some particular application areas) to get that wrong - among a litany of other common errors, I'm afraid. You can't be responsible if you're misled by people who should know better. $\:$ What do the original data consist of?  Are they measurements? Likert-scale values? counts? proportions?

Comment: The data is made up of measurements of DNA concentrations.

Comment: Are these concentrations effectively continuous proportions (values between 0 and 1, but not counts divided by totals?) ... if so, the variance will be related to the mean. (Knowing this may affect some potential answers)

Comment: Think of them like weights. No values between 0 and 1, but a range of values (1.44, 0.55, 0.71, 1.04, 2.03.. for example)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the Kruskal-Wallis one-way analysis of variance test. It is a nonparametric analog of the ANOVA F-test.

The Kruskal-Wallis test will assess the evidence against the null hypothesis that the populations are the same. If you find a statistically significant result (like via low p-value), then you might conclude that at least one of the population's distributions is greater than the others. The K-W test will not tell you which population is the one that is different (i.e. greater than or less than, roughly speaking) from the others.

If your goal is to also assess which population's distribution differs, you might look at Dunn's test (a nonparametric analog of Tukey's Honest Significant Difference test).

Comment: Whenever I try to use Krustal-Wallis on my samples using R, I get "Error en kruskal.test.default(LRNA, LISO) :   'x' and 'g' must have the same length"
So, I think a Mann-Whitney will probably do the trick :)

Comment: Mann-Whitney is inappropriate for more than two populations. I would advise you to Google the error and figure out what 'x' and 'g' are, then correct the issue.